# statistical test to determine the significance of an observation from a list of observations

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

I am observing mutations in a population. In a population of 2000, I get a list of locations with the number of affected individuals in the disease and the control.

I have done a boxplot of the `diseased_individuals` variable and `matched_control_individuals` variable and they are highly skewed.

Which statistical test can determine if location_1 is more significant than location_3 or vice-versa ?

|  | diseased_individuals | matched_control_individuals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| location_1 | 1000 | 1200 |
| location_2 | 100 | 85 |
| location_3 | 12 | 5 |

Comment: Welcome to CV. Could you please properly format your table so as to make it comprehensive?

Comment: Thank you so much! @J-J-J and extremely sorry for the wrong formatting. I read about markdown and tried to format  as above. in the draft section below the text writing area, it was being formatted as here, but the moment, i was posting, the formatting was lost. I tried several times. I don't know where was i making the mistake?

Comment: @AnubrataDas No problem, many people encounter problems with table formatting in markdown. Personally, I too have a hard time with it, so I generally create the table in Excel or LibreOffice, and then copy-paste it in an online markdown generator (like this one for example https://jakebathman.github.io/Markdown-Table-Generator/, but you can find many others online). It makes things much easier.

Comment: @J-J-J. Thank you so much!

Comment: can i use Fisher's extact test for each site?

Comment: Statistical tests test null hypotheses, which are probability models. I don't understand what the hypothesis is that you want to test. Do I understand your table correctly that there is only one observation for location 1 which is 1000 for the first and 1200 for the second variable? Or do these refer to numbers of cases? But then I don't understand why you talk about a population of 2000, as the table entries sum up to more than 2000.

Comment: yes. these refer to the number of individuals showing that condition. one individual can show multiple conditions. for each location, i want to test the null hypothesis, that there is no difference between the number of diseased and control individuals, given that we have  monitered that many people. i am sorrry for giving population size as 2000. it should be 2200.

Comment: So you want to test whether for example 1000 vs. 1200 is compatible with the null hypothesis that the probability to end up on either side is 0.5? The  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test does that. Note though that it isn't very meaningful to complain the strength of significance between locations, because you should expect a smaller p-value ("more significant") with larger sample sizes. I think it's more meaningful to compare the location-wise proportions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChristianHennig. this is a huge help. regarding the proportions, if i compare only the proportions, i will miss out the significance of the larger samples, which i think is important too. is there some way to combine both the sample size as well as the proportion?

Comment: @AnubrataDas Well, the test does that by definition, however as a result of this it isn't very meaningful to compare the significance over different sample sizes. I think you'll just have to live with the fact that compraing proportions makes some sense but comparing significances over different sample sizes doesn't tell you much.